# Cypress - can't run tests after upgrading cucumber preprocessor

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, esbuild

in package.json I used these versions of cucumber and esbuild with cypress:

```
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,ts}"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.5.1",
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.5",
    "cypress": "^10.7.0"
  },
```

In **cypress.config.js** I have:

```
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/features',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const createEsbuildPlugin =
      require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild').createEsbuildPlugin
      const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor')
      require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin

      on('file:preprocessor',   createBundler({
        plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
      }));
    }
  },
```

Now, this is working fine, no issues. But after I upgraded the cucumber preprocessor to:

```
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.2",
```

and cypress version to `12.3.0`

then ran **npm install** and started **cypress test runner**, I can't run any test.

After starting the test runner, however **I can see all my tests there**, but after I click any test, there is an error: **Cypress could not detect tests in this file** and this:

```
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/common-ancestor-path/index.js:17:37: ERROR: [plugin: feature] Reduce of empty array with no initial value
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1605:15)
    at C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1251:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1034:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1249:7)
    at C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1358:14
    at C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:666:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:763:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:632:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

When I downgrade the cucumber preprocessor and cypress, it is working again. Is there anything I should change in config file or what is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

I tried both versions, `"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.2"` worked ok but I did have to modify your config in line with the sample on the badeball repo:

- awaiting the `addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin()` call
- passing in the `on, config` params
- returning the config at the end of `setupNodeEvents()`
- putting a wildcard into `specPattern` (could explain test-not-found error)

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    // baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",

    // prefix async
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const createEsbuildPlugin = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild').createEsbuildPlugin
      const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor')

      // await here
      await require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config)

      on('file:preprocessor',   createBundler({
        plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
      }));

      // return any mods to Cypress
      return config
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this solution, i also removed node modules folder and cleared the cache, but now after clicking a test I have this error: Error: Build failed with 1 error:
C:\Users\JS\Desktop\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:255:12: ERROR: Invalid option in build() call: "watch"

Comment: The way to go might be to create a clean project with latest everything, then copy across your tests. Speaking of which, I used @badeball DuckDuckGo example test as proof-of-life. Suggest a step-wise approach checking at each step. When you find a test that fails, add it to the question.

Comment: not sure how to update esbuild itself, as in package.json I have only cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.5". But now I replaced esbuild with browserify, and I have no such an error.  But now the only issue is, it can't recognize And, etc.  it says: And is not a function. Strange that it has no problem with When. I will do further investigation.

Comment: Ok, I just learned, the And command should be used only in feature files and in step definitions only When, Then. Strange, that it was not a problem for years I used it till now :) So I replaced all And commands with When in js files and now  everything works with browserify

Comment: You have to think of "And" as meaning "Repeat the previous clause", so it will work when it comes after "When" and "Then" and the meaning is different each place: ... but you can't use it as the *first* clause in the step code. And that makes total sense, since in English you shouldn't start a sentence with "And" (see what I did there :)?

Answer (score 2):

So as I still had issues with using esbuild, I replaced it with browserify:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const browserify = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));

  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
  
});
```

So now the package.json looks like:

```
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.2",
"@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "^3.0.2",
"cypress": "^12.3.0",
```

I also needed to replace all AND commands in step definitions js files, e.g.:

**Before:**

```
import { And, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"
And("I select Checkbox", () => {}
```

**Now:**

```
import { When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"
When("I select Checkbox", () => {}
```

As `And` should be used in feature files, and in step definitions only `When, Then`.

With this config the latest cypress works with the latest cucumber and browserify.

Comment: That's good you found a work around, but for the record (in case others refer here), I found ESBuild works ok too.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue, and was able to resolve it by updating cypress-cucumber-preprocessor:
`"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^16.0.3",`